# Не обновляется случайное число

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа

Написал массив, заполняемый случайными числами и проверку на то что б они не повторялись
Но всё равно встречаются повторы, проверял через отладчик, иногда выполнение заходит в проверку if, доходит до строки с обновлением случайного числа и тупо не меняет его, а идёт дальше и в конце записывает его в массив.

Ещё в массив добавляются нули, несмотря на то что он изначально ими заполнен.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся

```
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    srand(time(NULL));

    const int SIZE = 3;

    int currentVar;

    int randomNumbers[SIZE]{};

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        currentVar = rand() % 4;

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (randomNumbers[j] == currentVar)
            {
                currentVar = rand() % 4;

                j = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
            
        }
        randomNumbers[i] = currentVar;

        cout << randomNumbers[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выполняете `j = 0;` в цикле и затем продолжаете итерации. Заголовок цикла делает `j++`. И вы больше никогда не проверяете нулевой элемент. Отсюда дубли. Простейшая правка - `j = -1;`, но не делайте так никогда. Не говоря о том что это не последняя ошибка в вашем коде.

Простое правило: `for` полностью контролирует переменную цикла. Нигде в других местах её не надо менять.

Ещё один цикл упрощает код: `do/while` гадает пока не угадает число, которого нет в списке.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    bool found;
    do
    {
        currentVar = rand() % 4;
        found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (randomNumbers[j] == currentVar) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (found);

    randomNumbers[i] = currentVar;

    cout << randomNumbers[i] << endl;
}
```

**P.S.** Нормальное решение этой задачи - сделать [тасование Фишера — Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0) для массива из четырёх чисел `[0, 1, 2, 3]` и взять из него три первых числа:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    const int N = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    const int SIZE = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        std::swap(a[i], a[i + rand() % (N - i)]);
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если вы хотите получать **именно так**, с проверками — то вот как должно выглядеть ваше решение:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 3;

    int currentVar, randomNumbers[SIZE]{};
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        bool ok;

        do {
            ok = true;
            currentVar = rand() % 4;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                if (randomNumbers[j] == currentVar)
                {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }
        } while(!ok);
        randomNumbers[i] = currentVar;
        cout << randomNumbers[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

Ну, а если хотите поэффективнее — то примерно так:

```
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    int randomNumbers[SIZE]{};

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());


    int values[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    shuffle(values, values+4, g);
    copy(values,values+SIZE,randomNumbers);

    for(int i : randomNumbers) cout << i << "  ";
}
```